# Spring boot @ComponentScan. How to exclude all packages from scan except one subpackage or class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, component-scan

```
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.REGEX,
        pattern =
            "com.base.package.*"
    )
)
```

Under com.base.package. there is a class that I do not want to be excluded, how can I include this single class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is in the regex.  Let's assume you want to exclude all classes except one named `MyClass`.  You can use a negative lookahead to exclude it from the regex match.  Try the following.

```
@ComponentScan(
    excludeFilters = {
    @ComponentScan.Filter(
        type = FilterType.REGEX,
        pattern =
            "(?!.*MyClass)com\\.base\\.package\\..*"
    )
)
```